# how to detect if we dismiss keyboard programmatically and dismiss by tap keyboard in uitextview?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, uitextview, ios5

i need to get this infomation, how to detect if we dismiss keyboard programmatically and dismiss by tap keyboard in uitextview? both of them called

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

but how to detect it difference? can somebody give me some clue?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a notification observer and listen for certain events:

### UIWindow Class

```
// Each notification includes a nil object and a userInfo dictionary containing the
// begining and ending keyboard frame in screen coordinates. Use the various UIView and
// UIWindow convertRect facilities to get the frame in the desired coordinate system.
// Animation key/value pairs are only available for the "will" family of notification.
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyboardWillShowNotification;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyboardDidShowNotification; 
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyboardWillHideNotification; 
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const UIKeyboardDidHideNotification;
```

### Example

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@(keyboardDidDisappear)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: hi @WrightsCS i have try that, and both of them, still called all that notification, can you tell me another clue?

Comment: i just want to know what exactly method / event that will fired if we dismiss keyboard onscreen using "undock / split" (dismiss) button in uitextview button

Comment: Use the notification I used in my example. When the keyboard dismisses, you do what you need to do in a method that you create called "`keyboardDidDisappear`"